# Can’t run apt update after installing and setting up wireguard

Tags: server, wireguard

As mentioned in the title, after installing and setting up **wireguard** I can’t update or install anything on my **VPS**, I’m running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

```
root@149:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,330 kB]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16), connection timed out C ould not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com: 80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19), connection timed out Coul d not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com: 80 (2001:67:1562::18), connection timed out
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [772 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,014 kB]
Get: 8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [706 kB]
Fetched 5,044 kB in Imin 29s (56.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Done
15 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could no t connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1:19), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not con nect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an outage ongoing on the APT repository. We are also experiencing issues on our side in our CI while using `apt` and there are other reports of such problems today (see [here](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/44171) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450044/aws-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-ec2s-cant-apt-get-update-from-aws-archive-503s/1450066#1450066))

Comment: It looks it got fixed at least for me, did it for you ?

Comment: @Kristian Yes, it got fixed for me too ;)