# aws ubuntu 22.04 jammy ec2s can't apt-get update from aws archive 503s

Tags: apt, aws

As per title, unable to apt-get / apt anything and index appears down for ap-southeast-2.

I have a collection of ec2s for a kubernetes lab cluster for a workshop, so I'm bringing it up and down every hour or so, no changes on my end today, I'm just verifying my set-up docs for users with fresh clusters.

This has been the situation a lot this week, and frequently today, anyone else dealing with this?

I can ping the address and IPs successfully.

the ec2 image: `ImageId: ami-0e040c48614ad1327`

`apt update` to illustrate:

```
root<@ip>:/var/snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656# apt update
Ign:1 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 13.210.201.60 80]
Err:2 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 13.210.201.60 80]
Err:3 http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 13.210.201.60 80]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
83 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 13.210.201.60 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 13.210.201.60 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 13.210.201.60 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@<ip>:/var/snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656#
```

```
[apt update output][1]
```

Comment: This is more an AWS issue than one for Ubuntu. 503 means the server is not available or responding with gibberish. If the 503s continue for an extended period of time (an hour or more), you may want to get in touch with Amazon to see what's going on 

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an outage ongoing on the APT repository. We are also experiencing issues on our side in our CI while using `apt` and there are other reports of such problems today (see [here](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/44171))